# Flow Check Error: fjs.parentNode.insertBefore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Here's the code

```
// Load the SDK asynchronously
((d, s, id) => {
    let js = null;
    let fjs = null;
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

Here's flow check error:

Cannot call `fjs.parentNode.insertBefore` because property `insertBefore` is missing in null or undefined [1].

How to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it could not find a `<script>` tag for some reason. So, let's instead try appending it onto the document somewhere:

```js
// Load the SDK asynchronously
((d, s, id) => {
    let js = null;
    let fjs = null;
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
    (fjs ? fjs.parentNode : document.lastElementChild).insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

That seems to fix it. I hope this helps. Alternatively, I would recommend doing the following if you need to load the SDK on a production website. Using `setTimeout` with a `0ms` delay is equivalent to `setImmediate` when not nested more than 4 deep.

```html
<script>setTimeout(function(){var d=document, s=d.createElement("script");s.id="facebook-jssdk";s.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";(d.head||d.all[1]).appendChild(s)},0);</script>
```

My snippet above will asynchronously load the script immediately after the DOMContentLoaded event so that `window.onload` is not blocked. My code should work decently in IE4+ and best in IE10+, but the sdk may or may not work in such old browsers.